# QWT Installation trouble

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator, qwt

I'm trying to install QWT for QT Creator on Windows 10 x64. I'm totally new to this framework.

Following the guidelines:

1. Setup the newest QT Creator with (QT Mingw 7.3.0 x32 and Mingw
   7.3.0 x32 tool)
2. Run mingw 7.3 and run following commands:

   - qmake qwt.pro
   - mingw32-make (here i have many "DEPRECATED" warnings on compilator run.
   - mingw32-make install
3. After it completes, I add path to `QWT\lib` in environment variables.
4. In user variables, I add `QMAKEFEATURES` with `qwt\features` variable.
5. In QT Creator project, created before, in file "*.pro" I add next strings:

   - INCLUDEPATH += C:/QWT/include
   - LIBS += -LC:/QWT/lib–lqwt

Also I include in the project header.

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qglobal.h>
```

Now, when I try to run an example project, I get the following error:

```
error: undefined reference to `QwtPlot::QwtPlot(QWidget*)'
```

Google says - that means unconnected QWT lib, but what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution found, im followed next steps:

1. In *.pro file im add

   CONFIG += qwt
2. Add additional user variable in enivromental variables

   QT_PLUGIN_PATH(QWT\plugins)
3. Add additional paths in enivromental variables

   C:\QT\Qtx.x.x\x.x.x\mingw48_32\bin

   C:\Qt\Qtx.x.x\Tools\mingw48_32\bin

I dont know which was helpfull, but now project compiles without any errors.